# How to properly color EditText in an AppCompat Toolbar pre-Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm trying to use an EditText in a Toolbar.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Test Text" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

On Lollipop, the EditText has its text colored as I'd expect, with the lighter text.

[image: Lollipop Version]

On pre-Lollipop, the text is colored using the darker text.

[image: Pre-Lollipop Version]

Without hard-coding the text colors directly on the EditText (or using a style to accomplish the same), is there a way to get consistent colors across versions? The EditText is getting its background tinted correctly pre-Lollipop, just not the text colors.

Answer (score 0):

Set textColorPrimary attribute in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   ....

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```